# COUNT() and EXPLAIN row's count are getting different

Tags: mysql, count, explain

In Mysql, I have a table (employee_by_range). I am getting rows using `count` and `explain`

*when am i trying to get rows using `COUNT()`, it's return **15880256** rows*

```
mysql> select count(1) from test.employee_by_range;
+----------+
| count(1) |
+----------+
| 15880256 |
+----------+
1 row in set (4.80 sec)
```

*when am i trying to get rows using `EXPLAIN` it's return **27912636** rows*

```
mysql> explain select emp_id from test.employee_by_range;
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------+
| id | select_type | table             | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employee_by_range | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 27912636 | NULL  |
+----+-------------+-------------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why both row's count are different ?

Comment: What storage engine does `test.employee_by_range` use?

Comment: innodb is used for this table